# Azure Active Directory Application with Microsoft Accounts

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm trying to use Azure Active Directory to authenticate users. I also want Microsoft Accounts (@live.com, @outlook.com, etc.) to be able to sign in to my application.

When I sign in with an AAD user, my application gets a Claim Value back from the login.onmicrosoft.com screen with the user's email address as the claim (user@mydomain.com).

When I sign in with a Microsoft Account user that I've added to my AAD, it returns a Claim Value of "live.com#username@outlook.com" which is perfect.

However, I also want random people to be able to sign in, not just users I add to my active directory. I want anyone to be able to sign in with their Microsoft Account, and it should give me the claim value so that I can create an account for them in my application.

Is there any way to allow these users to log in to my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 options:

- Add the MSA OWIN individual auth middleware alongside the OpenId Connect one
- If you want to experiment, we are integrating that feature in a future version of Azure AD: http://aka.ms/aadconvergence

Comment: Thanks, I used the AAD Convergence preview. It seems to be working. Only issue I still have is this line in the sample code: `// BUGBUG: Ending a session with the v2.0 endpoint is not yet supported.` Any idea when this will be supported? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-dotnet-web/

Comment: So I can't end the session normally. I got it to work by checking if the user has an AAD email or a Microsoft Email, and based on that, sending them to that service's logout URL. It's working now, thanks so much!